# Method Array First Odd Number

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I am stuck, I am trying to write a code that displays the first positive odd number in my index.
For some reason its not doing it. It just display whatever the first number is in my index. What am I doing wrong. I new so if you could help me I be very thank full. Also if you could keep is simple too thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] A = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };
    int index = FirstPosOddNum(A);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The first Positive value is: {0}, In Index {1}",
            A[index], index);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No positive odd value available.");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static int FirstPosOddNum(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((array[i] % 2 == 1) || (array[i] % 2 == -1))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Works for me:  "The first Positive value is: 5, In Index 1"

Comment: BTW your `FirstPosOddNum` function will also find a _negative_ odd number which doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Hint on how to fix that: `(negative odd number) % 2 == -1` and `(positive odd number) % 2 == 1`

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking that `Index 1` is the "first" number?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ((array[i] % 2 == 1) || (array[i] % 2 == -1))
```

To this:

```
if ((array[i] > 0) && (array[i] % 2 == 1))
```

You want to find the first **positive** and **odd** number, which is exactly what the condition in the `if` says.

Comment: I think the first check is not really required, `%` would only return `1` for positive odd numbers. For anything below `0` it will return `-1`

Comment: @Habib I am well aware of this. Except you're greatly confusing things for absolutely no reason. The requirement is positive and odd, so state it that way in the `if` condition. If the question asked for the first positive and *even* number, you'd have to include the positive check.

Comment: May be for readability reason, But it is just an extra check and I guess it would be fine specially for a new developer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = { -2, 5, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 };
        int index = FirstPosOddNum(A);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The first Positive value is: {0}, In Index {1}",
                A[index], index);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No positive odd value available.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static int FirstPosOddNum(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] % 2 == 1)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

A some of your comments said, you need to remove from your code your array[i] % 2 == -1

Comment: That doesn't change the output - the first odd number _is_ positive.

Comment: Yeah, and that´s the correct answer. If you try with int[] A = { -2, 6, -1, 9, -6, 23, 67, 1, -8, 7, -3, 90 }, the answer will be 9 in the index 3.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and ran your code. It is not having the problem you described. It is working as you want it to:

> displays the first positive odd number in my index

Maybe sure you Rebuild-All and are running the code you actually are seeing.

Also, make the change the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply say:

```
static int FirstPosOddNum(int[] array)
{
    int value = -1 ;
    for ( int i = 0; value < 0 && i < array.Length; ++i )
    {
      int x = array[i] ;
      if ( x > 0 && 0 != (x&1) ) value = x ;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Or (even simpler):

```
static int FirstPosOddNum(int[] array)
{
    int v = array.FirstOrDefault( x => x > 0 && 0 != (x&1) ) ;
    return v > 0 ? v : -1 ;
}
```